# Load static files in Django in a HTML page

Tags: python, html, django, image, static

How can i load static files such as CSS, JS or images etc., in HTML associated with Django?

I couldn't get even by reading the docs.

So, **I want a solution not a django docs link**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Added STATIC_DIR path and STATIC_URL both in settings.py.
And in HTML file...
{% load static %}
(next line)
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'myapp/template/static/style.css' %}"

Answer (score 1):

First, set your static path in settings.py. Add Static_DIR path exc.

In template start with

```
      {% load static %}
```

When you make a link in the header try this:

```
       <link href="{% static 'network/styles.css' %}?version=1" rel="stylesheet">
```

adding "?version=1" will solve your problem. It will get automatically updated version.

Comment: Also for direct includes:

_<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/style.css?version=1" />_

Comment: And you can use the same method for script files. Did it help?

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" this is what the error came

Comment: The solution works for me. Your path might be wrong. Be sure the folder/filename in the static folder. Check the error's url if this is right.